# Whats app System Design on sent, delivered read

Tags: architecture, system-design

Client A is offline: In this scenario, When the client came active, Do all the stored messages (in the phone) are sent by the client application to the server or after getting connected Whatsapp Server polls all the not sent message from the "Client A phone"? Is it a push activity or pull activity?
Client B is offline In this scenario: Does all the stored (undelivered)messages sent by the server to the client application or after getting connected Client application polls the pending messages from the Whats app webserver? Is it a push activity or pull activity?

Answer (score 0):

It could be implemented either ways.

I would rather go for a hybrid approach.

Usually when a device comes online (When internet is turned on), it would ask for any pending messages, which is a pull model. Then it can create a connection with the server and move to a push model.

This approach is described in much more details here: [WhatsApp System Design](https://youtu.be/RjQjbJ2UJDg)

For a short summary, refer to:  https://www.codekarle.com/system-design/Whatsapp-system-design.html

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a track of all messages exchanged between users and mark their sent and received status. Suppose B sent a message to A while A was offline, the message will be saved in the store as "not yet received by A". The first thing A should do after coming online is to check for all pending messages. At this point, A will receive B's message and it will be marked as such in the database.

Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjQjbJ2UJDg) video by [codeKarle](https://www.codekarle.com/). They have done a great job of explaining this!